# Filter condition not working on counter columns in ScyllaDB where it works in Cassandra 3.0

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have a use case where I am using filters on counter columns in cassandra. Now I am migrating to Scylla, and I see that scylla won't support counter column filters.

Does anyone know how to enable counter column filtering in Scylla?

Comment: Look like a bug
https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/5635

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counters are being actively developed at Scylla at the moment. Some features, like this one, have been intentionally left missing.
Please track this ticket: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/5635, I'll update you on the progress there and respond if you have any further questions.

EDIT: As you can see under the link above, the fix is already merged into upstream. It should be backported soon to the latest supported releases.

Comment: I  see one more issue with cassandra to scylla migration  => clustering key cartesian product size 200 is greater than maximum 100 , i am using datastax java driver to query. any idea??

Comment: @ROHANVADJE Please, open a separate question, with code and error message. I haven't used DSE ODBC driver with Scylla, but I'm sure my colleagues will help you.